# Problem with playing a sound when a button is clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

in my code:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"


- (IBAction)playSound{
    AVAudioPlayer *myExampleSound;

    NSString *myExamplePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myaudiofile" ofType:@"caf"];

    myExampleSound =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myExamplePath] error:NULL];

    myExampleSound.delegate = self;

    [myExampleSound play];

}
```

But it is showing a warning that Class MyViewController does not implement AVAudioplayerDelegate.

Anyone please help. I had included the AVFoundation.Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That warning should not affect the actual function of the code.

If you want to suppress the warning, in the header of your view controller do this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
```

This lets the compiler know that your class does respond to the AVAudioPlayerDelegate (even though all the methods in that protocol are optional). See [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html).